# Find if few array items exists in any one of many arrays?

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array, compare

Have these 2 Javascript arrays

```
// The player which has a "winning" combination (1, 5, 9)
player1Cells = [ 5, 9, 1, 6] 
// Player which doesnt have a "winning" combination
player2Cells = [ 2, 1, 4, 8]
```

A player has a "winning" combination if 3 of their numbers match one of the arrays in this array:

```
winningCombinations = [
    [1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9],
    [1, 4, 7], [2, 5, 8], [3, 6, 9],
    [1, 5, 9], [3, 5, 7]
];
```

In the example, `player1Cells` has a winning combination - 1, 5, 9. The other player doesn't

I figured there is a way to loop through the `winningCombinations` in some way, and compare it against the player compare but I don't know best approach to comparing these in an efficient way.

Comment: please add your attempt. btw, means *find* the combination or just if any?

Comment: `winningCombinations.some(combination => combination.every(n => player1Cells.includes(n)))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `some` method on the winning array and then `filter` method to check if player has more than 3 matches as current array in some loop.

```js
const w = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9],[1, 4, 7], [2, 5, 8], [3, 6, 9],[1, 5, 9], [3, 5, 7]];
const player1Cells = [ 5, 9, 1, 6];
const player2Cells = [ 2, 1, 4, 8];

function check(arr, p) {
  return arr.some(a => {
    const match = p.filter(e => a.includes(e));
    return match.length >= 3;
  })
}

console.log(check(w, player1Cells));
console.log(check(w, player2Cells));
```

Answer (score -1):

You may use:

- [`Array.prototype.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)
- [`Array.prototype.every()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every)
- [`Array.prototype.includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)

**Working Example:**

```js
let player1Cells = [5, 9, 1, 6];
let player2Cells = [2, 1, 4, 8];

let winningCombinations = [
    [1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9],
    [1, 4, 7], [2, 5, 8], [3, 6, 9],
    [1, 5, 9], [3, 5, 7]
];

let checker = function(w, p) {
  return w.some(a => a.every(v => p.includes(v)));
}

console.log(checker(winningCombinations, player1Cells));
console.log(checker(winningCombinations, player2Cells));
```